# Extending existing Wi-Fi network without changing it

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wds, wireless-extender

I have WRT54GL router with Tomato by Shibby firmware. Can I extend existing Wi-Fi network without changing the configuration of the main router? I read about AP + WDS mode but it seems in every tutorial that I have to configure it also on the primary router side.

I also have TP-Link WA850RE which is able to "extend"(repeat?) the signal with different SSID but I have no idea how this is working under the hood (WDS/Repeater/Bridge/Whatever).

Comment: What is the big deal about configuring the primary router? You will get much better behavior with real bridging than you will with faked repeating. Why is this such an obstacle for you?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz theoretically I can access the primary router but first of all I wanted to know if there is any possibility to do it without any changes. (TP-Link somehow is doing it) But if the performance hit is so nasty I will try do it  the other way.

Comment: It's not just performance, it's correctness. This kind of fake repeating relies on NAT and breaks very easily. WDS is real bridging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.   Simply get an access point (or get a router and disable WAN and DHCP functionality on it), and connect the devices LAN ports together.

If you use the same SSID (but different - and ideally non-overlapping frequencies), you will even be able to roam seemlessly between AP's.
You don't need to worry about WDS or repeat/bridge/whatever mode if you can cable the routers together using ethernet (or even using Ethernet over powerline if you can't do it directly), and you will get a faster, more robust network.

Using a repeater is another possibility, but they suck.  (they will just re-broadcast your existing WIFI, but will reduce the overall performance - so you trade range for speed)

Comment: What do you mean by `connect the devices LAN ports together`? The router I have has the Access Point option but then it just connects to existing network and shares it only via cable. Maybe my question was not precise but I want receive and send the signal in the same time.

Comment: That makes no sense - sned and receive signal is implied.  Are you saying you are wanting to extend your WIFI without using a cable?   (In that case I'm not interested in advising, because I don't believe in using repeaters)